# Как создать подобную форму?

Tags: javascript, php

Скажите, что за скрипт здесь применяли, чтобы сделать такой бланк заявления (прокрутите ниже на http://bloomotion.com/affiliate_becomeaffiliate.php). Дело в том, что заполнив анкету, он автоматически все выполняет без подтверждения админа. Подскажите.

Comment: А что он собственно выполняет?

Comment: Он добавляет аффилиатов автоматически на страницу
без проверки модератором)))

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то это добавление кнопки сайта внизу страницы. А если так, то в чем собственно проблема, пользователь закачивает картинку, текстовые данные проверяются на валидность скриптом (email и url). Адрес банера добавляется в базу для ротации на сайте. Т.е. все вместе - это строчек 30 кода - максимум.

Comment: Эм а можно мне этот код написать? плииииииииииз

Comment: Чет я реально не понял смысла вопроса! Проблема в создании формы? Боже, это элементарно


Comment: ну что тута не понятно? мне нужен код ээтой штуки

Comment: @олька, дык есть <a href="http://free-lance.ru" target="_blank">free-lance.ru</a>, вам туда. У вас не вопрос, а заказ.

Answer (score 1):

Форма добавляет в таблицу поле вашего баннера, после чего снизу цикл выводит банеры обратным отсчетом 5шт

```
SELECT * FROM banner order by id desc limit 5
```